# PHP Check if date is past to a certain date given in a certain format

Tags: php

I have a php event's calender which queries the database to get the dates.

I display the event date using:

```
$event['date']
```

and this display's in this format:

`2013-07-31` for example.

Now, what I need to do is to check if this date is a past date to the current date.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

You can compare the dates with PHP's [`DateTime`](http://php.net/datetime) class:

```
$date = new DateTime($event['date']);
$now = new DateTime();

if($date < $now) {
    echo 'date is in the past';
}
```

---

Note: Using `DateTime` class is preferred over `strtotime()` since the latter will only work for dates before 2038. Read more about the [Year_2038_problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem).

Comment: I would highly recommend using `$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2013-07-31');` instead. OP's example is ISO8601 format, so there is a strong chance of the DateTime class "figuring it out" correctly every time, but for varying DateTime formats, it is much safer to specify the date format you are instantiating from to ensure there are no hidden errors in the transformation.

Comment: @Wes I like your approach =)

Comment: Note, if `$event['date']` is today's date (without a time) this will consider it "in the past".  To compare dates without time you can do `$now = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'));`

Answer (score 27):

You can use [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [`time()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php):

```
if (strtotime($event['date']) < time()) {
    // past date
}
```

Comment: This should be the easiest method.

Answer (score 12):

@Satch3000 You've accepted the wrong answer as a right solution ( @Amal Murali )

Please see the output, Here I input the today date but it returns current date as past date.

```
<?php

/* Enter today date */
$date = new DateTime("09/14/2017");
$now = new DateTime();

print_r($date);

print_r($now);


if($date < $now) {
    echo 'date is in the past';
}
```

**Output will be**

```
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2017-09-14 00:00:00.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => UTC
)
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2017-09-14 07:12:52.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => UTC
)
date is in the past
```

**Solution**

```
$Date1 = strtotime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2017-09-15') ) ).' ';
$Date2 = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));

  if($Date1 < $Date2) {
        echo 'date is in the past';
    }
```

Comment: But... 2017-09-14 00:00:00.000000 _is_ before 2017-09-14 07:12:52.000000.

Answer (score 4):

```
if (time() > strtotime($event['date']))
{
    // current date is greater than 2013-07-31 
}
```

[strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) parses the date sting using [these rules](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php).