# Checking DateTime always returns date is in the future

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp

I am [attempting to compare two dates](https://3v4l.org/0gCRM) to see if it is in the past or future

But even thought the "DateToCheck" is in the past, it always returns "in the future". If the date is set for the future, it also returns in the future.

I used this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19031235/php-check-if-date-is-past-to-a-certain-date-given-in-a-certain-format) as a primer to check.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set( 'UTC' );
define( "TIMESTAMP_FORMAT", "Y-m-d G:i:s" );

$aString = "2017-03-01 23:11:16";
echo "String to convert: ". $aString ."\r\n";

$currentTime = date( TIMESTAMP_FORMAT );
echo "Current Time: ". $currentTime."\r\n";

$dateToCheck = new DateTime($aString);
echo "Date To Check: ". $dateToCheck->format(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT)."\r\n";

if($dateToCheck < $currentTime) {
    echo 'Date is in the past';
} else {
    echo 'Date is in the future';
}
```

Comment: First, check server time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your server **date is correct**, then you can use:

```
if (new DateTime() > new DateTime("2017-03-01 23:11:16")) {
    # date is in the past
}else{
    # date is in the future
}
```

Comment: This works, but why does your version work when my doesn't? To me, they appear to be essentially the same thing.

Comment: I think it has to do with `$currentTime = date( TIMESTAMP_FORMAT );` which isn't a datetime object.

Answer (score 0):

Try use epoch seconds:

```
if($dateToCheck->format('U') < $currentTime->format('U')) {
    echo 'Date is in the past';
} else {
    echo 'Date is in the future';
}
```